# JWT as mail verification token

Tags: security, token, jwt

Is there a reason not to use a [JSON Web Token](http://jwt.io/) for mail verification?

I would create the token with the users mail and a expire time and then check the token when the user clicks the link. That way I don't have to store the token in a Database.

But I'm wondering if an attacker can extract the secret key because he can control the mail-input and estimate the expiration time in the token?

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this for a while and personally I don't see any holes in using a JWT for verifying a user's email address, however my one concern is if the user changes their email address, and the token has not expired, what would happen if the user reused the old token, would it verify the new email address?

Hmm, it seems like you'd have to plan this right, but I see no issues security wise. Have fun!

Comment: according to https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/, "Sign your tokens with a strong key that is available ONLY to the authentication service. Every time you use a token to authenticate a user, your server MUST verify that the token was signed with your secret key." How certain are you that putting jwt as email activation url is secure?

Comment: @momokjaaaaa you could always sign non-auth based tokens with a different secret key. I would recommend doing it that way anyway.

Comment: @momokjaaaaa and onto that, the tokens aren't carrying a payload that is really that important, JWT are exposed to the local storage and are commonly passed through headers and URLs anyway. I think as long as you have a HTTPS connection, should be fine imo :/